# Adding a character in front of a list

Tags: python, list

To post a few hashtag on twitter I need to add # in font of the tags. The code:

```
s = ['Compile ', 'With ', 'Code'] 
print(*s, sep="\n#")
```

This code produces :

```
Compile 
#With 
#Code
```

However there is no hash character in front of the first element `Compile`. How can I add `#` in front of first element also?

Comment: `[*map(lambda x: f'#{x}', s)]`

Comment: Your question is unclear: Are you trying to _keep_ your list elements as they are and just `print` them with the hashtag, or is it okay to change the strings in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions, right?

```
output = ["#"+x for x in s]
print(*output,sep='\n')
```

Returns:

```
#Compile 
#With 
#Code
```

Or in a single line:

```
print(*["#"+x for x in s],sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am just trying to understand this code. Its not printing a new line though!

Comment: That's strange, copy pasting either proposed solution does add the line! If this helps you solve it, feel free to accept it. Otherwise let me know what's troubling and we'll figure it out :)

Comment: So issue is that i need to save it in a variable with new line. Since the variable needs to be passed to post in twitter. I cannot print it

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the higher order function map to prepend the '#' symbol:

```py
s = ["Compile ", "With ", "Code"]
result = map(lambda x: "#" + x, s)
print(*result, sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` and list comprehension

```python
s = ['Compile ', 'With ', 'Code']
s = ['#'+word for word in s]     # Add hashtag symbol to each word
output = '\n'.join(s)            # Join hashtags using new-line character
print(output)
```

Result:

```
#Compile 
#With 
#Code
```